# How do I handle a Cognito auth redirect for a Lambda / API Gateway for UI?

Tags: amazon-web-services, authentication, authorization, aws-api-gateway, amazon-cognito

When I go to my Cognito auth page

```
https://example.auth.us-east-1.amazoncognito.com/login
  ?response_type=token&client_id=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
  &redirect_uri=https://example.com/
```

I can successfully log in. Then I get redirected to

```
https://example.com/
  #id_token={token-goes-here}&access_token={another-token-here}
  &expires_in=3600&token_type=Bearer
```

Or something similar.

I have a custom Cognito authorizer set up for the root (`/`) endpoint. But the Cognito authorizer can only look in headers for that JWT.

I tried setting up a redirect that did noting except move the value of the fragment's `id_token` into an `Authorization` header, but the header was not passed on to the target `Location`.

Comment: Hi @benwiz, have you found any work around this issue? Currently I am facing same issue.

Comment: @SagarDeshmukh I ended up giving up on this. Maybe I will return to it in the future.

Comment: It is 2020 now. Has anyone found a solution? Thanks.