# How to use cognito id token as authorization header for API gateway?

Tags: aws-api-gateway, amazon-cognito

I have an API http gateway (at say https://example.com) integrated with an API REST gateway which uses a Cognito authorizer. All of this to serve a single-page React application. The behaviour is as expected:

- I launch the Cognito hosted UI and sign in,
- It redirects to the url https://example.com/#id_token=123
- If I use PostMan, I can access that url if I pass that id_token in the Authorization header.

Now my question is: how can I pass the header automatically after signing in so I can visit https://example.com?

I have spent a long time on this and have found many similar posts without an answer:

- [How to use the code returned from Cognito to get AWS credentials?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45785898/how-to-use-the-code-returned-from-cognito-to-get-aws-credentials)
- [How can I link cognito token and API authentication header automatically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66611612/how-can-i-link-cognito-token-and-api-authentication-header-automatically)
- [AWS Cognito hosted UI returning id_token in URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59005135/aws-cognito-hosted-ui-returning-id-token-in-url)
- [How can I make the redirect_uri of AWS Cognito (Hosted UI) authenticated?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67154840/how-can-i-make-the-redirect-uri-of-aws-cognito-hosted-ui-authenticated)
- [Set Authorization header when redirecting client from Cognito to AWS API Gateway](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67357513/set-authorization-header-when-redirecting-client-from-cognito-to-aws-api-gateway)
- [How do I handle a Cognito auth redirect for a Lambda / API Gateway for UI?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47613253/how-do-i-handle-a-cognito-auth-redirect-for-a-lambda-api-gateway-for-ui)

Answer (score 0):

We faced the same question a couple of years ago. Our solution was creating a proxy (using API Gateway and Lambda) that "moved" the `id_token` (stored in a cookie) to the `Authorization` header for every request to the server. It was ugly, but it worked.

BTW, getting `id_token` in the URL is how `Implicit Grant` works. But `Implicit Grant` is generally considered less secure than `Authorization Code Grant`. We have since migrated from `Implicit Grant` to `Authorization Code Grant`. However, we continue to use the proxy pattern (again using API Gateway and Lambda) as follows.

1. Exchange the returned `code` for `access_token` and `id_token` at the Cognito user pool's [token endpoint](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/token-endpoint.html). Store the tokens in a DynamoDB table with `session_cookie` as the partition key. Return the `session_cookie` as a cookie (with `HttpOnly`, `Secure` and `SameSite=Strict`) to the browser.
2. For each request from the browser, use the cookie to find the token in the DynamoDB table and put the token in the `Authorization` header.